# Meaning of a pattern using conditional

Tags: grammar

<del>Old title: Conditional patterns comparison</del>

Recently, I stumbled on new grammar patterns using the conditional form the following way (and I could not find an explanation in any of my grammar books) :

- 名詞・形容動詞＋なら＋形容動詞＋で
- 連用形＋たら＋た＋で
- 動詞: 已然形＋ば＋連用形＋た＋で
- 形容詞: 已然形＋ば＋終止形＋で
- 形容動詞: 已然形＋ば＋語根＋で
- 名詞: であれば+ 名詞 ＋ で

Example: 休んだら休んだで、たくさんやることがある。

<del>The author of the website that explains this pattern says that the particles で can be replaced (in most case) by ほど.</del>

In which case, で is better that ほど　?

I modify the question, what is the meaning of this pattern ?

The website which explains the pattern is [here](http://www.imabi.net/l57conditionalsii.htm).

Comment: So what are you asking exactly?  Are you asking about comparing the patterns as the title seems to indicate, or more about で／ほど?

Comment: The author of the website says that if you came up with a sentence `休めば休んだで...` and are told it is wrong, then most likely you confused で and ほど and should construct your sentence as `休めば休んだほど...`.

Comment: ~~ば~~ほど (eg 休めば休むほど/お金はあればあるほど/部屋は広ければ広いほどetc.) has a different meaning: "The more ~~, the more~~" http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9 (休んだら休んだほど sounds awkward. 休んだら休んだだけ sounds okay but it also has a different meaning.)

Comment: I though that で and ほど were more or less equivalent here but I am apparently wrong. So I would be interested in knowing what does mean the pattern using で.

Answer (score 2):

By replacing *de* by *hodo*, I suppose, the author of the website is referring to a similar (as he thinks) construct of an utterly different meaning.  It is explained in his web page explaining *hodo*.

As for the expression with *de*, it means something similar to its former half only.  The repetitious construction is often used, for example, to describe an undesired consequence (e.g., having lots of things to do) of a condition that is seemingly preferable (e.g., taking a rest).

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that they look similar in form, not that they have any similar meaning. The OP, I believe, is confused about the fact that this construction exists. And, it just so happens to starkly resemble the conditional + ほど pattern. Because of this, when students mess this up, they tend to conflate them. It's not that they have any similarity in meaning.